# jQuery autocomplete - TypeError: autocomplete is not a function in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm trying to add the jquery autocomplete on my dropDownList with the @url.action, but for some reason it doesn't work. It looks like I have all neccesary jquery loaded. I've tried everything (at least the one I've found in the site or in google).

**My HTML + js**:

```
<input id="test" name="test" />

@section scripts
{

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetCitiesForAutocomplete", "Students")'

        });
    });
</script>
}
```

**My Controller Students**:

```
    public JsonResult GetCitiesForAutocomplete(string term)
    {
        return Json(GetCities()
                    .Where(x=>x.Text.ToLower()
                    .Contains(term.ToLower())), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private List<SelectListItem> GetCities()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem> 
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Jerusalem", Value = "0"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Haifa", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Tel Aviv", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Katzrin", Value = "3"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Beer Sheva", Value = "4"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Netanya", Value = "5"}     
        };
    }
```

My question is:
How i do autocomplete in my dropdownlist only with the text in list.

For ex:
If i have press on 'je' -> i get 'Jerusalem'

If i have press on 'te' -> i get 'Tel Aviv'

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Jquery UI AutoComplete or [this one](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)?

Comment: @MihirSolanki I'm using Jquery UI AutoComplete

Comment: I think you need to pull the result of `@Url.Action("GetCitiesForAutocomplete", "Students")` into a JSON object and use that as the source.  As it appears, you have autocomplete dong filtering as well as the JSON method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the GetCitiesForAutoComplete method to return all cities. Autocomplete will handle the filtering.

```
public JsonResult GetCitiesForAutocomplete()
{
    return Json(GetCities(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```